# How to use boost::beast to connect to Coinbase's websocket API

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, coinbase-api, beast-websockets

I'm a bit new to websocket programming. I've been trying to use this example :- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp to connect to the coinbase websocket api over here :- https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#websocket-feed

However, I keep getting 400 - Bad Request in the response on wireshark.

Here is a snapshot of my TCP request :- [image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Which version of boost were you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out I am really new to web programming. The standard TLS port is 443. Also, coinbase's TLS api requires you to only set the hostname in the SNI field and not the hostname:port

Otherwise, the example worked as is!